# How can I retrieve corresponding words of each embedding in word2vec.py (tensorflow)?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

What word2vec.py does is returns a tensor of shape (vocab_size,embedding_size). I want the corresponding word of each embedding,sorta like a dictionary :

```
{ word1 : embedding1 , word2 : embedding2 .... }
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use word2vec._id2word to get index to id.